# fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) operation blocking the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm creating an app that display's gifs in a collection view.
I'm downloading the JSON from the GIPHY public API, then getting the data from each individual GIF URL and using `FLAnimatedImage` to store the data in a `UIImageView` before displaying them in a collection view.

I've forked the `FLAnimatedImage` `pod`, and added `NSCoding` protocols so the data is archivable in Core Data.

In my `collectionView` I'm using `fetchedResultsController` to fetch the objects that populate my `collectionView`.

Due to paging, my API calls for new images every time I get halfway down the images in my `collectionView` (single column single row) in `cellForItemAt`.

The call to get new Images is async, and as soon as it returns with results from a `fetchRequest`, I update the collection view. This does not block the main thread.

Now here's the issue: I save each GIF once I get the data from the download task as a `FLAnimatedImage` in my core data stack. Now unarchiving it causes the creation of the FLAnimatedImage for each image to run again, which causes a lot of CPU overhead because the problem is creating a `FLAnimatedImage` is very CPU heavy and so is unarchiving it off the stack. So both these operations are done for new batches of images while paging and eventually my app crashes.

The slowdown originates from each `fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)` call, and I am using a `backgroundContext` so I know it's not the thread I'm on. I think it's just overall CPU overhead that's causing the crash. But isn't `fetchedResultsController` supposed to have pulled the entity off the stack? Why is it unarchiving it and creating the attribute type(FLAnimatedImage) in the `fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)` call?

Is there a way I can store `FLAnimatedImage` on the stack that won't require it to be recreated every time I pull it off the stack with `fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)`?

Can you think of a strategy that might help?

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GSGifCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GSGifCollectionViewCell

    let gifObject:NSManagedObject = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

    gifObject.managedObjectContext?.perform {
        let gsGifObject = gifObject as? GSGif
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.imageView.animatedImage = gsGifObject?.image
            cell.rankLabel.text = "\(gsGifObject?.rank  ?? 0)"
        }
    }


    if let totalObjectsForSectionZero = fetchedResultsController.sections?[0].numberOfObjects {
        self.checkCurrentIndexPathAndGetMoreGifsIfNeccessary(indexPath: indexPath, totalObjects:totalObjectsForSectionZero)
    }


    return cell
}
```

is there something above I'm doing incorrectly?

Here's my archival code:

```
#import "FLAnimatedImage+NSCoding.h"

@implementation FLAnimatedImage (NSCoding)

static NSString *const kFLAnimatedImageCodingData = @"kFLAnimatedImageCodingData";

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    NSData *data = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kFLAnimatedImageCodingData];
    return [self initWithAnimatedGIFData:data];
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.data forKey:kFLAnimatedImageCodingData];
}

@end
```

This causes the main thread to block - [self initWithAnimatedGIFData:data];

Comment: It would be a good idea to post the output of the console with your question. That would be helpful in diagnosing your problem. Do you have Xcode set to set a breakpoint on exceptions?

Comment: this line in my cellForItemAt `let gifObject:NSManagedObject = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)` produces: Thread 1 EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address:_) error when scrolling

Comment: You are providing very little context of the line that causes your problems. We should probably seee the whole `cellForItemAt` method. `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` usually means you are reaching somewhere in memory where the system thinks you should not. This most often happened to my if I had some threading issue. Therefore you should give us some more info on what happens around that line. As a side note: Please update your question and do not add code in comments, formatting is just terrible there.

Comment: I updated my question with the whole `cellForItemAt` method

Answer (score 0):

First - core data is not thread safe - neither for reading or for writing.  So replace

```
 gifObject.managedObjectContext?.perform {
    let gsGifObject = gifObject as? GSGif
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.imageView.animatedImage = gsGifObject?.image
        cell.rankLabel.text = "\(gsGifObject?.rank  ?? 0)"
    }
}
```

with simply:

```
 let gsGifObject = gifObject as? GSGif
 cell.imageView.animatedImage = gsGifObject?.image
 cell.rankLabel.text = "\(gsGifObject?.rank  ?? 0)"
```

You going to and back to a background thread is not helping in any way and violates core data's rules for multithreading.

Next - storing a large blob of data in core data is generally not a good idea - as it wouldn't be a good idea in most relational databases.  Instead
either:

a) store the images in the documents directory and saving only the file path in core data.

b) make another entity that only has the data blob and make a relationship to it from the GSGif. this way the relationship is only loaded (in core data speak "faulted") when it is accessed.